# Как на Objective-C оправить post запрос с многомерным массивом типа ключ значение

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, rest, mobile-development

C приложения, написанного на Objective, нужно отправить POST запрос, в теле которого - многомерный массив типа "ключ":"значение".
Вот что формируем на Objective:

[image: Вот что на Objective]

Вот какой запрос получает сервер:

[image: Вот какой запрос получает сервер]

А вот что должно прийти:

[image: А вот что должно прийти]

Как построить объект на Objective чтобы data[address] пришло на HTTP сервер как указано на 3 картинке ?

Comment: Думаю, нам всем нужно с Вашим код ознакомиться, чтоб понять, как именно Вы формируете данный словарь, и что потом с ним вытворяете для того, чтобы передать в запросе.

Comment: OMG, что за странный формат. Почему ваш сервер не использует распространённый повсюду JSON?